# Why is the excel formula not pulling in all results horizontally starting with the first entry?

Tags: excel, indexing, formula

I'm trying to use the Index formula to pull in multiple results horizontally. The formula works partially in that it is only pulling every 5th entry instead of pulling in the first.

I've tried manipulated multiple areas of the formula to get it to pull in the very first entry. The only time it works is if I update my true statement to the exact number of instances that exist, but having to do this for all kind of defeats the purpose of using this formula then.

=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$1830|SMALL(IF($F2=$A$1:$A$1830|ROW($A$1:$A$1830)-ROW($A$2)+1)|COLUMN(G2:G2))|2)|"")

In this example, I should be getting '516' and then all following as I pull the formula across to the right. But instead, I get the 6th -9th.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7VRI.png)

Comment: What version of Excel are you using where `|` is the formula delimiter, instead of `,` or `;`?

Comment: Hi Bruce, Thank you for reviewing my question. I am using "|" via Windows 10. I manually changed my delimiter to pipes because of preference.